# Overload resolution failed because no accessible `Sleep` can be called with these arguments

Tags: vb.net, thread-sleep

I have the following code:

```
Dim MyFile As String
MyFile = ("C:\Book1.xlsx")
Dim infoReader As System.IO.FileInfo
infoReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(MyFile)
Threading.Thread.Sleep(infoReader.Length / 1000)
```

How can I solve the following error:

[image]

Comment: Use explicit conversion to required type. This should be understandable from error description, after all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your number (double) to a timeSpan:

```
Dim sleepTime As Timespan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(infoReader.Lenth/1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

The result a division operation (`infoReader.Length / 1000`) is a floating point number (`Double` in our case since `FileInfo.Length` property is of type `Long`).

On the other hand, the `Threading.Thread.Sleep()` overload you're most likely wanting to use expects an `Int` parameter.

Cast the division result to `Int` explicitly (is the files are not too big):

```
Threading.Thread.Sleep(CInt(infoReader.Length / 1000))
```

Or use the second overload accepting `TimeSpan`, using the `FromMilliseconds` method which accepts `Double`:

```
Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(infoReader.Length / 1000))
```

Comment: That's not right. The `/` operates using `Double`s and will only be a `Long` if you cast it afterwards. You can even see it in their screenshot

Comment: @AFriend: yes, you're right. Mixed up with C# division operator. Removing the answer...

Comment: Don't remove it, it's a good answer! Just edit it a little :)

Answer (score 0):

Divide it using the integer division. The sleep function doesn't take a double as parameter.

```
Threading.Thread.Sleep(infoReader.Length \ 1000)
```